Unable to start Docker Desktop after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
after recommendation from Ubuntu I upgraded to newer version Ubuntu-24.04. Upgrade finished without any errors. After upgrade, docker from the terminal is working without any problems, but I'm unable to start docker-desktop.
I totally uninstalled and cleaned docker-desktop and docker with all relevant folders docker and installed it again. But it didn't helped. Docker is running and I'm able to use it, but docker-desktop unable to start.
Then I run diagnostics: /opt/docker-desktop/bin/com.docker.diagnose gather.
In dmesg.err.txt I found following error: dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted.

in path ~/.docker/desktop/log/host/Docker Desktop.stderr.log I found an error: The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /opt/docker-desktop/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.. I set permissions by recommendation, Docker Desktop is now starting, but It will freeze on loading screen: docker engine is the underlying technology that runs containers. I don't know now, if it's next issue, or issue related with previous issue.

Step-1: Fix chrome-sandbox permissions, which break the start of docker desktop
sudo chmod 4755 /opt/docker-desktop/chrome-sandbox

Step-2: The latest Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is not yet supported by docker-desktop. Docker Desktop will fail to start. Due to a change in how the latest Ubuntu release restricts the unprivileged namespaces.
Run the following command at least once (in my case, I must run the command, then restart and rerun the command):
sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0

